# Start a new project in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code

There's a few things I'm having trouble with here that are related:

1. I'm trying to start a new project, but it keeps defaulting to the one I have open already. I can't seem to find a way to start fresh with a new project.
2. I can't figure out how to remove folders from the project. Say I added the wrong folder to my project and I want to remove it, how would I do this?

Thanks

Comment: If you open another project folder, will replace last recent folder.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

1. File->New Window seems to do the trick
2. The projects are filesystem based.  So if it's in your folder structure it'll be shown in VSCode;  I believe this is by design.  The only way to remove the folder would be to do so from the FS level.

Comment: But I don't want ANOTHER window ! Why cant this IDE be more intuitive like other IDEs in creating a new Project ? Spent quite some time trying to figure out the warped MS logic in developing Code. I think Allen's comment above is the right answer. Instead of creating new folder within Code, create it outside first THEN open it here. Aaaargh MS !

Comment: @killjoy: VS Code is more of a code editor than an IDE. We usually use it for editing rather than scaffolding your project.

Comment: As to the OP question; just use your cmd to create whatever type of project you want(Angular, web api, razor pages, etc...) and then open it in VS Code.

Comment: That doesn't create a new project, it just starts a new instance of VSC ...

Comment: @killjoy VS Code is not an IDE, its a text editor.

Answer (score 16):

1. Create a new Folder
2. Use VS Code to Open that empty folder.
3. Open the Integrated Terminal by selecting View\Terminal
4. In the terminal window, type `dotnet new console`.

This command creates a `Program.cs` file in your folder with a simple "Hello World" program already written, along with a C# project file named `HelloWorld.csproj`

Comment: Remember to download .Net Core, so that the dotnet commands work.

Comment: I hoped there's another way like "New project" in Visual Studio, but ok, I see VS Code has no functionality for creating projects using GUI. If I'm wrong, please, provide me with the way

Comment: It's possible to create the new project with any name (other than `HelloWorld.csproj`) by using the `-n` (or `--name`) option, e.g., `dotnet new console --name=MyLovelyProject`.

Answer (score 7):

Pressing shortcut

```
Ctrl + Shift + N
```

opens a new Window, which gives you the possibility to open a new folder.

On macOS it's

```
Cmd + Shift + N
```

Answer (score 6):

VSCode works primarily with folders.

If it discovers a .sln, project.json or global.json file in the folder you open, it will load them and allow you to switch between them.

The explorer will always show the filesystem, regardless of what project is currently loaded.

Also, on startup, VSCode will automatically open the last opened folder.

Answer (score 4):

OPen the terminal window In the terminal window, type

```
dotnet new console
```

. to start with new console application.

To Create ASP .net web API project

```
dotnet new webapi -n MyWebAPI
```

For any help

```
dotnet new --help
```

To build the project, In terminal type

```
dotnet build
```

To run the project, In terminal type

```
dotnet run
```

Answer (score 2):

Answered here - [Create C# .sln file with Visual Studio Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36343223/create-c-sharp-sln-file-with-visual-studio-code)

Open VS Code terminal and navigate to the directory where you want to create solution folder.
Use following commands

```
dotnet new sln -o MyApiApp
```

The -o parameter lets you specify the output directory

Navigate to solution direction

```
Cd .\MyApiApp\
```

Create new projects under root solution folder

```
dotnet new console -o MyApiApp.ConsoleApp
dotnet new webapi -o MyApiApp.WebApi 
dotnet new classlib -o MyApiApp.Repository 
dotnet new xunit -o MyApiApp.Tests
```

Add projects to solution (use tab to navigate path).

```
dotnet sln MyApiApp.sln add .\MyApiApp.ConsoleApp\MyApiApp.ConsoleApp.csproj .\MyApiApp.WebApi\MyApiApp.WebApi.csproj .\MyApiApp.Repository\MyApiApp.Repository.csproj .\MyApiApp.Tests\MyApiApp.Tests.csproj
```

Add project references

```
dotnet add .\MyApiApp.WebApi\MyApiApp.WebApi.csproj reference .\MyApiApp.Repository\MyApiApp.Repository.csproj 
dotnet add .\MyApiApp.ConsoleApp\MyApiApp.ConsoleApp.csproj reference .\MyApiApp.Repository\MyApiApp.Repository.csproj 
dotnet add .\MyApiApp.Tests\MyApiApp.Tests.csproj reference .\MyApiApp.WebApi\MyApiApp.WebApi.csproj .\MyApiApp.Repository\MyApiApp.Repository.csproj
```

Answer (score 1):

VS Code doesn't include a traditional File > New Project dialog or pre-installed project templates. You'll need to add additional components and scaffolders depending on your development interests. With scaffolding tools like Yeoman and the multitude of modules available through the npm package manager, you're sure to find appropriate templates and tools to create your projects.

Answer (score 0):

I like to open it via run command: code *path* . Make sure you have VS Code installation path added in your environment variable PATH.

Comment: This doesn't seem to fully answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

Right click the workspace and click add folder to workspace. Then add the folder you want to use.