# Create C# .sln file with Visual Studio Code

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code

I'd like to create a new C# solution with Visual Studio Code.

I'm using *yo* tools.

Now I have a folder with ASP project. And another folder with class library.

How can I reference class library from asp project?

Seems I have to add dependency to the *project.json*:

```
"dependencies": {
    "ClassLibrar.Name": "*"
}
```

But to make this possible I need solution file. But VS Code and *yo* doesn't create a such one.

VS Code can be used from different OS, while VS accessible only from Windows, I'd like o create a new solution with VS Code only.

Simple requirement: create web project and 1+ class libraries.

All this will be packed in docker container

Comment: Sounds like you need to create a new project from within visual studio really. Explain what is the problem please?

Comment: I'd like to create a new solution without VS, only VS Code

Comment: I use yeoman on mac, and was a matter of `yo aspnet` to get started. VS code is nowhere near VS proper, but it's great to be able to do real world c#.

Comment: You mean that all your solution was located in 1 project and you didn't test it? Why did you minus my question? :-)

Comment: VS Code is just a (fully featured and excellent) text editor; it doesn't support solutions which are a Visual Studio-specific feature.

Comment: I'm with @deeptowncitizen - have a folder with 2 projects, one a webapi project and the other a test project.  Don't to use VS - as I'm enjoying VS Code..and I've read you can use it for mulitple projects.. just not sure how to tell it which to run (as default project).

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Visual Studio Code provides a way to create the new project templates.

1. Navigate to Visual Studio Code terminal (press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd>)
2. Type the command `dotnet new sln`
3. You can also create the new project, check list of available project templates using command  `dotnet new list`.

The detailed documentation is **[Available Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-new?tabs=netcore2x).**

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42730946/908677 you can add projects to the solution using syntax like: dotnet sln add .\Foo\Foo.csproj

Comment: Those capabilities are provided by .Net - not by Vs Code. Even ht eC# DevKit [https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-dotnettools.csdevkit] does not seem to have this capability.

Answer (score 99):

Open VS Code terminal and navigate to the directory where you want to create solution folder. 
Use following commands

```
dotnet new sln -o MyApiApp
```

The -o parameter lets you specify the output directory

Navigate to solution direction

```
Cd .\MyApiApp\
```

Create new projects under root solution folder

```
dotnet new console -o MyApiApp.ConsoleApp
dotnet new webapi -o MyApiApp.WebApi 
dotnet new classlib -o MyApiApp.Repository 
dotnet new xunit -o MyApiApp.Tests
```

Add projects to solution (use tab to navigate path).

```
dotnet sln MyApiApp.sln add .\MyApiApp.ConsoleApp\MyApiApp.ConsoleApp.csproj .\MyApiApp.WebApi\MyApiApp.WebApi.csproj .\MyApiApp.Repository\MyApiApp.Repository.csproj .\MyApiApp.Tests\MyApiApp.Tests.csproj
```

Add project references

```
dotnet add .\MyApiApp.WebApi\MyApiApp.WebApi.csproj reference .\MyApiApp.Repository\MyApiApp.Repository.csproj 
dotnet add .\MyApiApp.ConsoleApp\MyApiApp.ConsoleApp.csproj reference .\MyApiApp.Repository\MyApiApp.Repository.csproj 
dotnet add .\MyApiApp.Tests\MyApiApp.Tests.csproj reference .\MyApiApp.WebApi\MyApiApp.WebApi.csproj .\MyApiApp.Repository\MyApiApp.Repository.csproj
```

Comment: Also in VS Code, if you have a complex nested folder structure, you can let VS Code do the folder path completion for you, by right clicking the `csproj` you would like to add. Then clicking `copy relative path`, then simply using `dotnet sln add` in the folder that contains the solution, then paste the relative path you copied :) saved me a lot of time.

Answer (score 16):

I find myself visiting this page, not for the first time, because I have already upvoted @Rahul-Uttarkar's answer.

Thing is, the answer is a solution using the terminal. It doesn't really leverage the fact that VS Code has a rich user interface, besides using the integrated terminal.

Things have moved on, there is a sweet little extension on the marketplace called [vscode-solution-explorer](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=fernandoescolar.vscode-solution-explorer) that allows you to create a `.sln` file, add/remove new/existing projects and more. Behind the scenes it's making command line calls which you'll see if your terminal window is visible.

EDIT: to explicitly create a new solution file with this extension, you need to have VS Code point to an empty folder. Then the extension will say "No visual studio solution found [learn more](https://github.com/fernandoescolar/vscode-solution-explorer#open-solutions) with two buttons below, "Open solution" and "Create New Solution"

Comment: I was about to create my own bash script to automatically create .sln files for me. It wasn't difficult, but this vscode-solution-explorer extension is SO good!

Comment: @user1007074  - I like that extension and it does good things with EXISTING .sln files. but I have not found (documenttion or empirically) the ability to create a NEW .sln [not using terminal]

Comment: @DavidV.Corbin thanks for taking the time to comment. Short answer is that, yes this extension can create new .sln files (the github readme has a little gif showing it). I have edited my answer to explain how to do it. I'll admit it's a little clunky, and it doesn't really allow for creation of multiple solution files in the same locaiton.