# VS 2017 ASP.NET Core MVC Unhandled Exception: System.IO.FileLoadException:

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-core

When I run an ASP.NET Core MVC I get the following:

Unhandled Exception: System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=4.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

Answer (score 2):

Cause: Corrupted NugGet cache, for example browserlink (see [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/dotnet/cli/issues/5528) or [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/7379) )

Solution: 
Delete the NuGet cache and run  `dotnet restore`. The  .nuget/packages directory is in the user's home directory on all operating systems (for example, /home/user1 on Linux or C:\Users\user1 on Windows).

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this same error after opening a project in VS 2017 that was initially coded and successfully run using VS Code.

Solution: Generate a solution file for use by VS 2017.  Using the integrated terminal in VS Code:

```
dotnet new sln
dotnet sln add myproj.csproj
dotnet restore
```

Then open the newly generated sln file in VS 2017.  Deeper discussion of this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42730877/net-core-when-to-use-dotnet-new-sln).